# Take time values into integer?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that looks like this:

```
["09:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "03:00 PM"]
```

I want to simply take these values and parse them into a integer between 0-24 basically, currently I'm taking it in like this:

```
if ("09:30 AM") { return 9.5}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: 1) Thats an array. 2) Use build-in date/time handlers.

Comment: Instead of writing an `if` statement for *every possible time* you could parse the numeric values you need out of the string and build the result dynamically.

Comment: 3) That's a decimal type, not an integer

Comment: @MikeBrockington `"03:00 PM"` must be `3` or `15`?

Comment: From the question:   return 9.5   - that's not an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution maps the time format input to a number between 0 (inclusive) to 24 (exclusive), just like the 24-hours format.

```js
function parse(dfmt) {
  const [hh, mmdp] = dfmt.split(":")
  const [mm, dp] = mmdp.split(" ")

  const hours = parseInt(hh)
  const minutes = parseInt(mm)

  return (dp == "AM" ? 0 : 12) + (hours % 12) + (minutes / 60)
}

const dfmts = ["09:00 AM", "03:00 PM", "09:30 PM", "12:00 AM", "12:00 PM"]
dfmts.forEach(dfmt => console.log(parse(dfmt)))
```

Comment: `parseInt` can be omitted for both `hh` and `mm`, since `%` and `/` both convert the the string to an integer. Furthermore `parseInt` without the `radix` parameter might also result in issues with older JavaScript engines, because [strings starting with a `0` used to be interpreted as an octal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#octal_interpretations_with_no_radix).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a methods to convert time to float number and then use map to call function on each item of your array. Now you have array of float numbers:

Here is working snippet:

```js
function timeStringToFloat(time) {
            var hoursMinutes = time.split(/[.:]/);
            var hours = parseInt(hoursMinutes[0], 10);
            var minutes = hoursMinutes[1] ? parseInt(hoursMinutes[1], 10) : 0;
            return hours + minutes / 60;
}

var data = ["09:30 AM", "12:00 PM", "03:00 PM"]

var d = data.map(t => timeStringToFloat(t))

console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function convertToNumber(val){
    let temp = val.split(' ')
    let temp2 = temp[0].split(':')
    let a = Number(temp2[0])
    let b = Number(temp2[1]) / 60
    let result = a + b
    if(temp[1] == 'PM')
      result += 12
    return result
  }
  
  ["09:00 AM", "12:30 PM", "03:00 PM"].forEach(e => {
    console.log(convertToNumber(e))
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. It parses "**12:00 PM**" to 12.0 and "**12:00 AM**" to 0.0:

```js
const times = ["09:30 AM", "01:24 AM", "03:00 PM", "12:00 AM", "12:00 PM"]

function time2Float(a) {
  return a.map(t => {
    const apm = t.split(" ")[1];
    let h = parseInt(t.split(":")[0]);
    let m = parseInt(t.split(" ")[0].split(":")[1]);
    
    apm === "PM" && h !== 12 && (h += 12);
    apm === "AM" && h === 12 && (h -= 12);
    m = (m * 100) / 60;
    return parseFloat(h + "." + m);
  });
}

console.log(time2Float(times));
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest approach is using `momentjs`'s `asHours()` function:

```js
let array = ["09:00 AM", "12:00 PM", "03:00 PM"]

array.forEach(val => console.log(moment.duration(moment(val, "h:mm:ss A").format("HH:mm:ss")).asHours()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Mac_3.2.57$cat getHours2.js
const getHours = (time) =>{
 let hours = time.replace(":", ".").replace(/[^1-9]*$/, "").replace(/^[^1-9]/, "");
 return hours;
}
console.log( getHours("7:30"))
console.log( getHours("12:30"))
console.log( getHours("07:03"))
console.log( getHours("7:30 PM"))
Mac_3.2.57$node getHours2.js
7.3
12.3
7.03
7.3
Mac_3.2.57$
```